# How to open a case in salesforce support

Tags: salesforce-support

i am getting internal server error in visualforce pages described in ([apex:dynamicComponent rerender gives 500 Internal Server Error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44286/apexdynamiccomponent-rerender-gives-500-internal-server-error).i) want to contact salesforce and want more details about my error.i goto link https://help.salesforce.com/hthome and click on contact salesforce after that i clicked on open a case.it shows login page.i logged in.its redirect me to same /hthome page with an error parameter passed in url https://help.salesforce.com/hthome?err=1 and i am unable to open my case.Please tell why i am not able to open a case ??

Comment: the url should be https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTHome, your current url is missing `/apex/`

Comment: tried your one also but same error :(

Comment: and you are using your production org credentials? you are able to log into salesforce successfully?

Comment: No i am using developer org credentials.dont have any production org.is it necessary to get production org for submitting a case ??

Comment: developer org are pretty much production orgs but with storage limitations. it should also work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce developer orgs do not have the ability to open cases with their support team.

I've known people who registered as consulting partners under their own personal name to get access to partner support, but I have no idea if that's something that's frowned upon by salesforce or not.

The developer forums are also [supposedly monitored by salesforce support staff](https://twitter.com/thisisnotapril/status/486938924908937216) but I have no idea how effective this is.

If you have a production org you can use for logging a case, do so (unless you're a partner, then use the partner portal). If not, you can try other options.

Comment: dang you wrote a better write up :/

Comment: @rao only because I was helping somebody who hit this issue last weekend!

Comment: well its always something new I learn from this forum :) and makes it worth spending every minute out here.

Comment: It's worth noting that salesforce hasn't really ever supported developer editions (I recall them closing my cases), they just got around to enforcing it in the Help & Training app.

Answer (score 3):

After looking around looks like you cannot open a case from DEV orgs anymore. Trying to find documented proof, will attach with this answer as soon I find it.