# Enable clickjack protection for non-setup Salesforce pages

Tags: visualforce, clickjacking

i want to enable the iframe on visualforce pages.i am going to disable it from

> Administration Setup" -> "Security Controls" -> "Session Settings

but it is disabled. how can i disable/uncheck it.

**Update:** 
 i want to uncheck:
 clickjack protection for non-setup Salesforce pages
  and 
 
 clickjack protection for non-setup customer Visualforce pages with headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can contact Saleforce.com Please see the screen shot below.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i am trying to open a case by selecting help link but it is not giving me permission to open case.i am having a  free developer account and want to disable it to do some R&D.so pls suggest me how it could be possible?

Comment: From Developer org we cant raise case to salesforce.  Please check the url below...   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44308/how-to-open-a-case-in-salesforce-support     Check you can try to do this in a production org get the support..