# Manage Currencies

Tags: multi-currency

How to Enable the Multiple Currencies for My salesforce organization
 According [this document](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_currency.htm&language=en_US) describes
                    but I dont have if i search Manage Currencies in the Quick Find box it is not showing in My salesforce organization why? Can anyone describe for the Answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Company Information page and hit edit button there you will find the setting to enable the multiple currency for your org.

[image: Multi currency checkbox]

> This setting is used to verify the specific organization that’s
>   approved for multi-currency activation. **It doesn’t submit a request to
>   Salesforce. Submit the request via your normal support process.**

So after enabling this feature you have to log a case for Salesforce support.

To **open salesforce support cases**, Please go through following links:

1. [How to open a case in salesforce support](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44308/how-to-open-a-case-in-salesforce-support)
2. [Unable to log salesforce support case from developer edition](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34186/unable-to-log-salesforce-support-case-from-developer-edition)
3. [Submit, create or update a case with Salesforce Support](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000123530&language=en_US)

Comment: I have activated that option ,but it is not showing Manage Currencies in the Quick Find box when I am Searching

Comment: You have to log a case to salesforce support from partner community.

Comment: what I have to Log a case Means? Please Describe I dont Know

Comment: How do I log a Case to salesforce Support

Comment: See updated answer and please read all the links carefully.