# How To get customers and opportunities info through Salesforce API

Tags: api, salesforcesdk

How can we get Customers info and Opportunities info in c# using salesforce api . or is there any API exist that can be used to get customers/contact info and opportunities info from salesforce API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Salesforce standard Rest API** to access the opportunities or any other object.

**Try [Workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com)**: It's an awesome tool where you can build rest-urls to access different type of data.

These are some REST-URLs to access different type of records from Salesforce.

[image: Opportunity Rest URLs]

Comment: Do i need to pay anything for that . As when i followed the workbench link it gives me error message "API is not enabled for organisation or Partner"

Comment: Check this doc: [Error, "API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner"](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005705) . For professional edition you have to purchase this.

Comment: I was alos on the same link i am having developer account don't how can i find whether i am using professional edition / developer as i am logged in on developeraccount i was assuming i am using developer edition

Comment: go to setup->search for "company information". There you will see **Organisation edition**.

Comment: I couldn't find API Enabled to check by following A & B Point point on the same link . there is no api enabled option to check .

Comment: yes i can see its Professional Edition . so Do i need to purchase EnterpriseEdition to get it working or to login to workbench Do I need to purchase Enterprise Edition

Comment: I don't think you need to upgrade org completely.I think you can request for API access feature only. from doc **For Professional Edition organizations, all requests for API access must be purchased and can be processed contacting your Account Executive.**

Comment: Thanks for the quality info you provided can you please let me know how can i make request to get access to that api

Comment: I think you would need to raise a Salesforce support case. In [this answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131511/manage-currencies/131513#131513) i have provided details how to raise a case.

Comment: do you mean i should raise issue in salesforce support

Comment: Yes.Provide the necessary information like org id of org in which you want the feature with that case.

Comment: ok i am having org id i will try to raise issue in salesforce support regarding this

Comment: "Thanks" here generally get well received when you mark the answer correct and close the question :P :)